# Wordpress - Remove separator when using previous_post_link() and next_post_link()

Tags: wordpress

I am using `previous_post_link()` and `next_post_link()` to show navigation on **single.php**. They are operated by a slash. Works fine but when you are on the first or last post the slash is visible which I don't think makes sense or looks good. I would like to hide the slash on the first or last post.

I have tried using the code below

```
<?php previous_post_link( '%link', 'PREVIOUS'); ?> | <?php next_post_link( '%link', 'NEXT'); ?>
```

I believe using something like if has previous and next post then display the slash would work, but I am not sure how to do that.

The slash always appears but I would like it to not appear on the first or last post.

Comment: Figured it out this way instead. Wrapped the slash in a span and used css: .slash:first-child, .slash:last-child {display: none;}

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$total_post_count = wp_count_posts();
$published_post_count = $total_post_count->publish;
$total_pages = ceil( $published_post_count / $posts_per_page );


<div class="more-links">
   if ($paged == 1) {
     <?php next_post_link('NEXT'); ?>
   } else if ($paged == $total_pages) {
     <?php previous_post_link('PREVIOUS'); ?>
     } else {
     <?php previous_post_link('PREVIOUS'); ?> | <?php next_post_link('NEXT'); ?>
       }
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could just use the paginate numbered links.

```
<?php echo paginate_links( $args ); ?>
```

Documentation for the latter [is here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links).

Comment: Thanks. How would I insert this in the code? What would it all be wrapped in?

Comment: You can put inside any div or section you use for your links.  I've added an example to the post.